# Is there a way to overwrite CKAN Javascript files in a plugin?

Tags: javascript, python, ckan

I'm writing a custom plugin for CKAN and in this plugin I want to overwrite the file https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/2.8/ckan/public/base/javascript/modules/image-upload.js from CKAN with a new implementation. Is there a way to do this?

I tried adding the file on the same path in the plugin, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a fanstatic directory in your extension and move the files there. Then use `add_resource` function to register that directory as explained [here](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/theming/fanstatic.html#). As an additional example check this extension([register](https://github.com/keitaroinc/ckanext-datarequests/blob/master/ckanext/datarequests/plugin.py#L109), [directory](https://github.com/keitaroinc/ckanext-requestdata/tree/master/ckanext/requestdata/fanstatic))